# Using value of a string inside a method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to use the value of a string inside a method. Everything is mentioned inside a class.

```
public class export_inspections_page extends BasePage {

public @FindBy(css = "div.checklist-details-title.no-padding > div")
    WebElement extract_TitleName;

String ExtractedCLTitle = extract_TitleName.getText();

    public static boolean verifyPDFContent() throws IOException {

        PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("/Users/user/Downloads/1960_ANewChecklistTemplate1Updated_BigTurnip_280618 (18).pdf"));
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        String text = pdfStripper.getText(doc);
        doc.close();
        System.out.println(text);
        System.out.println(ExtractedCLTitle);
        Assert.assertTrue(text.contains(ExtractedCLTitle));
        return text.contains(ExtractedCLTitle);
    }
```

Right now I am not able to access the string inside my "verifyPDFContent" method.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You are trying to access a non-static field from a static context. Make the field static or make your function non static

Comment: remove the `static` keyword from `verifyPDFContent()`

Comment: Also `String ExtractedCLTitle = extract_TitleName.getText();` will throw a `NullPointerException`, because `extract_TitleName` will not be initialized

Comment: Yes, i am getting nullpointer there. How do i fix it?

Comment: @moh17 : where is your driver initialization ? you are getting null pointer exception because of that.

Comment: Driver initialization is in a totally different page. Why is it causing a problem now?

Answer (score 0):

> You are trying to access the non-static variable from a static method,
>   which isn't allowed.

So now you have 2 options either make `ExtractedCLTitle` **static** or make your `verifyPDFContent` method **non-static**